# data-icons not visible in android

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have used jquery mobile with phonegap to establish app in andriod.When i browse the app in the browser(safari,chrome) the data-icons shows up, but after publishing to the andriod markets the data-icons are invisible. Any help appreciated.

The css for the data-icons to display is given below:
background-image:url(/images/icons-18-white.png);

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you have included the image as well, have you ended the CSS correctly?
If you debug i locally, does it work then? If yes, Google Play has something to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

try without the first slash: `background-image:url(images/icons-18-white.png)`

This worked for me at least.